# Extract authors meta data with XPath

Tags: c#, xpath, web-scraping

I have a series of HTML-files where authors names are split into first and lastname, contained in meta tags.

My current HTML structure is as follows, I want to extract authors first and lastname in a correct way, so that I can use this data to index these HTML-files. The amount of authors may vary between HTML-documents.

```
<!doctype html>  
 <html lang="en">  
 <head>
 <title>Title of document</title>
 <meta charset="utf-8" />  
 <meta name="dcterms.title" content="The science papers title" />  

<meta name="author" />
    <meta name="firstname" content="Eddard" />
    <meta name="lastname" content="Stark" />

<meta name="author" />
    <meta name="firstname" content="Tywin" />
    <meta name="lastname" content="Lannister" />

<meta name="author" />
    <meta name="firstname" content="Jon" />
    <meta name="lastname" content="Snow" />

 <meta name="dcterms.subject" content="The articles subject" />  
 <meta name="description" content="The articles description, abstract or introduction" />  
 <meta name="keywords" content="keyword1, keyword2, keyword3" />
</head>
```

I have bee using C# and XPath to scrape this data, trying to figure out how to get data correct. My problem is that I can't seem to figure out how to extract the meta data and make look like this, so I can use each string variable in generating XML later.

```
var author_1: Eddard Stark
var author_2: Tywin Lannister
var author_3: Jon Snow
```

My current C# test bed with XPaths.

```
            var url = "<URL TO DOCUMENT>";     
            var web = new HtmlWeb();
            var doc = web.Load(url);
            var navigator = (HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNodeNavigator)doc.CreateNavigator();

            // Xpaths
            var authors_list = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//meta[@name='author']");
            var authors_FirstName = "//meta[@name='author']/following::meta[1]/@content";
            var authors_LastName = "//meta[@name='lastname']/@content";

            // Laboratory
            var listOfAuthorsXpath = "//meta[@name='author']/following::meta[1]/@content";
            var nodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(listOfAuthorsXpath);

            // SelectNodes
            var firstName = navigator.SelectSingleNode(authors_FirstName);
            var lastName = navigator.SelectSingleNode(authors_LastName);

            // Print to screen
            Console.WriteLine(firstName.Value + " " +lastName.Value);

            //Console.WriteLine(doc.DocumentNode.InnerHtml);
            Console.ReadKey();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Updated Answer]
(Please notice that the XML that you share is not a valid XML, a `</html>` is missing)

With this snippet you can get the information that you need:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Xml;

namespace XPath
{
    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.Load(".... your file");

            // Xpaths
            XmlNode root = doc.DocumentElement;
            // Xpaths
            XmlNode root = doc.DocumentElement;
            XmlNodeList xmlFirstNameNodeList = root.SelectNodes("//html/head/meta[@name='firstname']");
            XmlNodeList xmlLastNameNodeList = root.SelectNodes("//html/head/meta[@name='lastname']");

            List<String> authors = new List<String>();

            for(int i=0; i<xmlFirstNameNodeList.Count; i++) {
                authors.Add(xmlFirstNameNodeList[i].Attributes["content"].Value + " " + xmlLastNameNodeList[i].Attributes["content"].Value);
            }

            Console.ReadKey();

        }
    }
}
```

The content of List authors:

```cs
authors[0] = "Eddard Stark"
authors[1] = "Tywin Lannister"
authors[2] = "Jon Snow"
```

Comment: Yes, correct. I forgot to mention that these meta tags are located in the HTML head section. I've updated the question.

Comment: Still, the document isn't a valid XML. Is missing the closing tag of HTML node.  Also I have a doubt, are you sure that the tag author does not contain the 2 tag firtsname and lastname?

Comment: The document is a valid HTML document, iahve just not pasted the entire document here. You answer is somewhat correct, but I don't want first and last names on separate rows. That makes no sense.

Comment: Ok updated to have first and last names on the same row. But please notice that without an XML schema we have no guarantee that the element with first name will be always followed with the last name. That is an assumption that we do.

Comment: Yes, it seems good. So you are suggesting that this XPath: "//html/head/meta[@name='firstname' or @name='lastname']" is better? 
As I am indexing a series of HTML-documents, I am not printing authors names to screen. They would rather be assigned to a author variable like author1: Eddard Stark, author2: Tywin Lannister, author3: Jon Snow and so forth..

But I guess I can use each of the attributes, @name to assign first and lastname to concatenate a full name?

Thank you for helping :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194060/discussion-between-gixlg-and-christer-johansson).